# Logging to FluentD with dotnet core?

Tags: .net, logging, fluentd, .net-core

I'm using fluentd as a log aggregator in front of an elasticsearch db. I started working on a dotnet core api and want to add my logs there as well. Is there a good package for this? So far I've found the Nlog and the fluentd target are not compatible with core.

Answer (score 3):

Use Serilog with the corresponding [Fluentd sink](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Fluentd)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stumbling on this answer the proposed lib by @carlos-mendible has a memory leak and has not been updated since 2019. I created a [fork](https://github.com/klyse/serilog-sinks-fluentd) and published a fixed version on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Fluentd.Revived)